# Scala Spark create extra column with ACL using filter expression

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

Good day collegues.

- This is a profile restriction

```
((col1 = valueA 3) or (col2 = ValueB 2)) - Common  sql expression
((NOT col1 = valueA N) and (col3 = ValueC 2)) - It could be with all kind of logic operators
```

. I have a source dataSet, for examle:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
|   Col1    |   Col2   |   Col3   |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| ValueA 1  | ValueB 2 | ValueC 3 |
| ValueA 1  | ValueB 3 | ValueC 4 |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

And i need to get next dataset:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   Col1    |   Col2   |   Col3   | Profile1 |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ValueA 1  | ValueB 2 | ValueC 3 |        1 |
| ValueA 1  | ValueB 3 | ValueC 4 |        0 |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

- 1 - means that filter function returned true
- 0 - means that filter function returned false

I know how to do it with join(do filter source dataset by sql_expr, join withColumn and so on).
But i have about 100 profiles and i won't do 100 joins.
I am not looking for ready solution, but some advice how to make it effectively will be to the point.
I think i could somehow create collection of profiles restriction(profile_id, sql_expression) and do map for every row, create a column with Array that contains inside correct profile_ids and after all do flatmap.

**UPDATE1:**
Currently i use this solution, but can't test it because locally it  never ends.

```
    @Override
    public <V extends SomeData, T extends ObjWithRestr> Dataset<Row> filterByMultipleRestrictionObjs(Dataset<V> source,
                                                                                                          List<T> objsWithRestr,
                                                                                                          Class<V> tClass) {
        Dataset<Row> resultDataset = source.as(Encoders.bean(Row.class));
        for (T objWithRestr : objsWithRestr) {
            Profile profile = (Profile) objWithRestr;
            String client_id = profile.getClient_id();
            ProfileRestrictions profileRestrictions = gsonAdapter
                    .fromJson(new StringReader(objWithRestr.getRestrictions()), ProfileRestrictions.class);

            String combinedFilter = getCombinedFilter(profileRestrictions.getDemoFilter(), profileRestrictions.getMediaFilter());
            Dataset<Row> filteredDataset = resultDataset.filter(combinedFilter);
            Dataset<Row> falseDataset = resultDataset.exceptAll(filteredDataset).withColumn(client_id, lit(0));
            Dataset<Row> trueDataset = resultDataset.intersectAll(filteredDataset).withColumn(client_id, lit(1));
            resultDataset = falseDataset.unionByName(trueDataset);

        }
        return resultDataset;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# With the help of below approach you can be able to solve the isseue i believe

Your filter condition values
filter_col1|filter_col2
valueA 3|ValueB 2
valueA 4|ValueB 3
valueA 5|ValueB 4
valueA 6|ValueB 5

//read them and conver them into a dataframe - filter_cond_df
//Create temp table on top of filter_cond_df
filter_cond_df.createOrReplaceTempView("filter_temp")

Your input Data:
+-----------+----------+----------+
|   Col1    |   Col2   |   Col3   |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| ValueA 1  | ValueB 2 | ValueC 3 |
| ValueA 1  | ValueB 3 | ValueC 4 |
+-----------+----------+----------+

//consider this as input_df, create a temp table on top it
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_temp")
//to get only the matching for your filter condition
val matching_df = spark.sql("""select * from input_temp where col1 in (select filtert_col1 from filter_temp) or col2 in (select filter_col2 from filter_temp)""")

//get the remaining or not matched from your input
val notmatching_df = input_df.except(matching_df)

//adding profile column with value 1 to matching_df
val result1 = matching_df.withColumn("profile"),lit(1))
//adding profile column with value 0 to notmatching_df
val result2 = notmatching_df.withColumn("profile",lit(0))

val final_result = result1.union(result2)

i hope this helps!
```

Comment: @Sangam.gavine this is a cool solution.
But my filter sql_expression has value like (not ValueB=1) , that's why i can't create a temp table.

I have found solution, where i can create MapFunction that create DataSet with single row, do filter, and if it dataset size 1 write record with 1, if dataset size = 0, write record with 0. But i don't like it, because it has a lot of overhead. I have to create multiple datasets.